# EOperation Parameter as EList

Tags: emf

Is it possible to pass an EList Parameter to an EOperation? I tried to set the Upper Bound of the Parameter to "*", which was marked as invalid.

The EList that'll be passed will contain Objects of an class that i defined in the same ECore model.

I currently use EMF 2.10

Answer (score 0):

Setting the upper bound to -1 did the trick instead of *